# Shell Script- each unique user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a homework assignment: "for each unique user, report which group they are a member of and when they last logged in"

So far I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Your initial login:"
who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq

echo "Now is logged:"
whoami

echo "Group ID:"
id -G $whoami

case $1 in
   "-l") last -Fn 10 | tr -s " " ;;
   *)    last -Fn 10 | tr -s " " | egrep -v '(^reboot)|(^$)|(^wtmp a)|(^ftp)' | cut -d" " -f1,5,7 | sort -uM | uniq -c
esac
```

My question is: how I can show the each unique user? The script above only show the more recent user logged in the system, but I need all unique users.

Can anyone help?

Comment: ... since your're quoting something, mind sharing what you're quoting? A homework assignment perhaps?

Comment: do you know the `last` command?

Comment: then you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Script using `last`

```
#!/bin/bash
while read user; do
  echo "User '$user':"
  echo -e "\t Last login: $(last -1R "$user" | awk 'NR==1{if($0 ~ /^$/){print "Never"}else{$1=$2="";print}}')"
  echo -e "\t Groups: $(getent group | awk -F: -v user="$user" '$0 ~ user{a[i++]=$1} END{for(item in a)printf("%s ", a[item])}')"
done < <(getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

#### Output

Names have been changed to protect the innocent

```
User 'foo':
         Last login:  Oct 19 15:07:19 -0700 2010
         Groups: foo groupA groupB
User 'bar':
         Last login:  Nov 16 11:40:23 -0800 2008
         Groups: bar groupA groupC groupD
User 'baz':
         Last login: Never
         Groups: baz groupA groupD
```

Comment: wow your script is a bit hardcore to understand, but i will try

Comment: i test and received the message "never login in the system" for all users

Comment: @Dinis perhaps your `lastlog` command is a bit different than mine. Could you update your question with about 5 or so lines of the output of `lastlog`. Try to include lines that show all the different variations of the output, i.e. some show an IP/hostname, some show some variation of "Never" and the rest show the actual date.

Comment: @Guys, maybe you're not using the same locale. In that case, `awk -F'Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun'` probably won't work for @Dinis.

Comment: the cmd lastlog never retrieve a login time of the users, i tried last -u root, and receive the same message "never login in the system"

Comment: @Hamidi possibly. Due to the way `lastlog` was written to output data by separating fields only by whitespace, I see no other way to delimit the timestamp if one exists.

Comment: @Dinis I don't know what to tell you, it looks like my script is working correctly but for some reason your `wtmp` file is not being updated correctly.  Certainly `lastlog -u your_user` should report back something other than "Never login in the system"

Comment: i confirm with another person that have the same distro and he have exact same problem with cmd lastlog

Comment: @Dinis how about just the `last` command? Does that output actual timestamps for your users?

Comment: @Dinis see my updated answer with the script that uses `last`

Comment: You should be using `getent passwd`, because your users may not be stored in archaic plain text files, but, say, an LDAP tree.

Comment: @user well, to be fair, `/etc/passwd` may be archaic but it is also certainly pervasive. In either case, using `getent passwd` doesn't hurt so I've updated my script to reflect this. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The following link has some alternate ways of listing users. They involve reading `/etc/passwd`.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/How_to_list_all_your_USERs

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no other way than reading `/etc/passwd`, for example:

```
$ for u in `cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1`; do echo $u `id -Gn $u`; done
```

Comment: one question, if i use your script i receive haldaemon 495,
gdm 486,
convidado 61000,
what is that names?? i don't have that users

Comment: @Dinis, there are many "system" user accounts on UNIX systems, each having a specific role. For instance, `haldaemon` is the user the hardware abstraction layer daemon runs under.

Comment: ok thanks for explanation , but for search real users like root, or another user?

Comment: @Dinis, that would be trickier. One way would be to filter `/etc/passwd` and only return the users whose shell (last field) matches one of the lines from `/etc/shells`, but even that doesn't guarantee you won't get false positives (or even false negatives, e.g. you might have disabled user accounts whose shells will be set to `/sbin/nologin` but still represent "real" users).

Comment: that script: 
for u in `cat /etc/passwd |grep /bin/bash |cut -d: -f1`; do echo $u `id -G $u`; done one of the parts, but for last access by each user i think the unique choice is the command last or not?

Comment: @Dinis, yes, `last $u` will do the trick. In passing, note that your filter will exclude users that prefer alternate shells like e.g. `tcsh`.

Comment: "useless use of cat" invocation there.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through any unique user you could get the content of the `passwd` file and get the first token of each line.

I'd suggest using `getent passwd` to read `passwd`, since `/etc/passwd` only contains users from local machine files (eg: no users from LDAP or other PAM plugins).

```
getent passwd | cut -d':' -f1
```

This command will return one user per line.

Then `last` and `id` will tell you their last login and their group:

```
for user in `getent passwd | cut -d':' -f1`
do
    id ...
    last ...
done
```